# Time into Dropdown Value in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, time

Since I still do not have enough reputation to join in a chat room or comment on other questions, I would like to ask this. I already displayed the current time on a specific field but then, I want to get that value to be displayed in dropdown inputs. my whole code is on this plunker file : http://plnkr.co/edit/4XRjszIATgvUVrofgRFI?p=preview

I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you very much

```
 <span my-current-time="format">
      {{dropdownValue}}
  </span>
 </div>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <select ng-disabled="isCheckboxSelected('1')" ng-model="format.time" >
       <option value=  "<span>{{format }}</span>"> <span>{{format }}</span></option>
  </select> 
  <span>{{format}}</span>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I know is to use **[ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)** in `<select>` .

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
      ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id"
      ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select>
```

Here is a demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/5KlBnmnKzxvTU8R3zUaa?p=preview

Reference: 
[Using select with ngOptions and setting a default value (AJS Documentation)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Comment: does this means I have to write time range data values under scope.data?? @Rohit

Comment: no, that is just an example: In your case I guess the value you want to show in dropdown is in `format` variable.(Guessing)
So it will be like  `ng-option = "format.time for format in format ..."` . See how ng-options works.

Comment: and if it is not too much for me too ask can you give me a plunker sample?it is ok if you cant :) @Rohit

Comment: your code is way too long. Reduce the example to the specific problem and give a plunker here. Maybe then i can rectify.

Comment: what I want is also to display the time value on the respective dropdown.Thank you @Rohit. You're being a great help :)